# Tumblr-style GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, tumblr

Been searching for a library that can create a gridview similar to tumblr's /archive page.

example: sweethomestyle.tumblr.com/archive or any tumblr blog then /archive

What it does is keep the aspect ratio of the images but make them all fit into the screen. I know its a word for this but I'm not sure what it is.

I would like to replicate this in android, the images will be all different sizes.

[image: Tumblr /archive example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this library would work for you https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

Comment: While I cannot say rather this library works or not, it is Exactly what I've been lookin for. Thanks @Alex.

Comment: This library does actually work!..with a couple issues. i.e. gets stuck when scrolling back up to top of gridview and an issue with images filling column widths(semi-fixed by using 4 columns instead of 3). But with a little tweaking I think it'll come out right. If anyone have an idea to address the issues I've listed please let me know as I believe this is a viable solution for what I've been looking for.

Comment: I did not used the library personally because not needed to create something like this...yet. You can try to report the bugs on the projet's github page.

Comment: the StaggeredGridView has many issues, and they can be found easily by rotating the screen after some scrolling. i suggest using a different library. i've posted a new suggestion if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

recently i've posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557720/gridview-with-different-cells-sizes-pinterest-style).

i recommend the [**PinterestLikeAdapterView library**](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView).

note that even though its sample is very modest, it can have the same behavior...