# Android Grid View Like Galaxy Tab Wall paper

Tags: android, android-gridview

i want to make Grid View like below image

[image]

**just Grid View with different image size with CheckBox. i want to run this in API 8 to API 19**

i have already tried [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) but it is depend on Image size. if all images are same size then its look like simple Grid View.

it is possible. want some suggestion.

Comment: What suggestions do you need now ? You are going on right track.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest checking out [**this library**](https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView).

i've also made a post about it, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557720/gridview-with-different-cells-sizes-pinterest-style) .

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Quilt View](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary).may be it will help. i haven't used it but it might help

Comment: but its working in > 3.0 API. and we can not able to add checkbox to select images.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful libraries for implementing Pinterest-like grid view:

- https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo
- https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView
- https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView
- https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall

Answer (score -1):

make your own `ViewGroup`, override `onMeasure` and `onLayout`.
or, make your own `View`, override `onDraw` and `onTouch`.