# Android RecyclerView StaggeredGrid items changing position on scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, staggered-gridview

My problem is that the items keep interchanging when  I'm scrolling through the list. How can I make their position fixed?

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1sp"
    >


        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/network_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:padding="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subreddit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/network_image"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/author"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="New Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I put the visibility of the text on gone, because I think the image is the one that keeps moving the objects. Is there any way in which I can fix this interchanging of items ?

AdapterCode:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewRowHolder> {

private List<ListItems> listItemsList;
private Context mContext;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private int focusedItem = 0;
String[] urls = {"http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03020/ANIMALS_GOOSE_3020723k.jpg","http://www.evolo.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/New-York-Vertical-Central-Park-Jeffrey-Lee-Rui-Liu-Tina-Qiu-01.jpg"};

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<ListItems> listItemsList,ImageLoader imageLoader){
    this.listItemsList = listItemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mImageLoader = imageLoader;
}

@Override
public ListViewRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int position){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    ListViewRowHolder holder = new ListViewRowHolder(v);


    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView redditUrl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.url);
            String postUrl = redditUrl.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", postUrl);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewRowHolder listViewRowHolder, int position) {
    ListItems listItems = listItemsList.get(position);
    listViewRowHolder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);

    listViewRowHolder.getLayoutPosition();

    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(2);

    Log.d("photos",listItems.getThumbnail()+" "+ listItems.getUrl());

    listViewRowHolder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(urls[n], mImageLoader);
    listViewRowHolder.thumbnail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.image1);

    listViewRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getTitle()));
    listViewRowHolder.subreddit.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getSubreddit()));
    listViewRowHolder.author.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getAuthor()));
    listViewRowHolder.url.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getUrl()));
}

public void clearAdapter(){
    listItemsList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return (null != listItemsList ? listItemsList.size() : 0);
}


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaggeredGridLayoutManager and moving items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636999/staggeredgridlayoutmanager-and-moving-items)

Answer (score 3):

Here already answered:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
manager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

[Android - StaggeredGrid items disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695165/android-staggeredgrid-wrong-items-disposition/36758964#36758964)
and in github project [Picasso/Glide-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/yuvaraj119/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating imageloader object again and again create the object at the adapter constructor and use this

```
listViewRowHolder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(urls[n], mImageLoader);
```

in onBindViewHolder and why are you using random to get the url use the fixed url and use position to get that

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: urls is just a String array with 2 items in it. I'm using random to return either 0 or 1. Those are not the actual urls. You can look at the first lines and see that it's defined there.

Comment: And I added the ImageLoader in the constructor but nothing changes