# StaggeredGridView changing item sizes on scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I have run into this problem

Am using a staggered grid view and it has a combination of two columns and single columns..Something like this

[image]

everything works fine, until i scroll up and down a few times and it randomly changes to something like this

[image]

A few more scrolls and it ended up like this

[image]
I have no idea why and its very random. I tried to do a notifyDataSetChanged each time the page is shown, and does'nt seem to do anything

This is the code for my dashboard

```
public class DashboardStaggered extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    View v;
    MasonryAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("MASONRY", "onCreateView");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(v==null) {
            Log.d("MASONRY", "v is NULL recreating");
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboard_staggered, container, false);
            setupRecyclerView();
        }else{
            Log.d("MASONRY", "v is NOT NULL");

        }

        return v;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(){
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.masonry_grid);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        adapter = new MasonryAdapter(getActivity(),this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(12);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("MASONRY", "onResume");
        if(mRecyclerView==null) {
            setupRecyclerView();
        }



    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("MASONRY", "onPause");

    }

}
```

If needed i could post the adapter too. Any suggestions are highly appreciated folks.

Adapter code here(don't want to make the post messy) http://pastebin.com/QkZbjjp1

Trimmed code http://pastebin.com/Hgsji1RG

Comment: Show your adapter code please. If you're doing any background operations that may be the culprit.

Comment: Added to the post Jason, please take a look

Comment: Sorry, much too hard for me to dissect what's going on in there.

Comment: Json, trimmed down unrelated pieces of code. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but one potential cause is on line 77 you should be using the `getItemViewType` method since that's the method that defines the view types.

Comment: As mentioned in Jason's comment, I also think that the problem is in your `getItemViewType()` method. You're not handling the ViewType depending on the position, you're just changing the type for the first (position 0) and the last one (position 11), but for the rest of positions, you're using the same type `TILE_TYPE_ONE_COLUMN__TILE`.

Comment: Hey Jason, not sure what you are referring to? can you help me out here?

Comment: you miss row & column for each item

Comment: I think i see it. Let me try it guys

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the problem. I totally missed it, thanks for pointing it out. Should i answer my own question, or will someone take the honor? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaggeredGridLayoutManager and moving items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636999/staggeredgridlayoutmanager-and-moving-items)

Comment: @Veeru Do you have a full version of this demo source?  I am attempting to get something similar up and running, but instead using horizontal layout (max two rows) - filling in top, down, left-right, and running into some complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jason mentioned in the comments, it was a blunder in itemgetviewtype, logical error more than anything else. But lesson learnt, the updated code for getItemViewType is

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Return type based on position
        return tileDefinitions.get(position).getTileType();
    }
```

Thanks everyone for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Glide to load the image, add dontranform() function and set adjustviewbound to true in the image view.

Eg:

```
Glide.with(context).load(image.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .dontTransform()
                .into(holder.image);
```

In the layout file:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the holder dose not recognize the width and height of the Image view when you scroll up and down. It clears the upper view when you scroll down and vice versa.

Use like this :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    MyViewHolder vh = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
    ImageModel item = imageModels.get(position);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) vh.imageView.getLayoutParams();
    float ratio = item.getHeight() / item.getWidth();
    rlp.height = (int) (rlp.width * ratio);
    vh.imageView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    vh.positionTextView.setText("pos: " + position);
    vh.imageView.setRatio(item.getRatio());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.getUrl()).placeholder(PlaceHolderDrawableHelper.getBackgroundDrawable(position)).into(vh.imageView);
}
```

For clear see this link:
[Picasso/Glide-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/yuvaraj119/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find this answer below, it may helpful for you. use below library,

> ***flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.2***

use below Input List:

```
const List mylist = [  
  {"img": "assets/images/img_1.png", "title": "Logan"},  
  {"img": "assets/images/img_2.png", "title": "Candyman"},  
  {"img": "assets/images/img_3.png", "title": "Angry Birds"},  
  {"img": "assets/images/img_4.png", "title": "Rocket Life"},  
]

Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.8,
          // child: Text("data"),
          child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            itemCount: SearchVideoList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: new Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image:
                                AssetImage(SearchVideoList[index]['img']),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => new StaggeredTile.count(
                index == 3 ? 2 : 1,
                index == 0
                    ? 2
                    : index == 1
                        ? 1
                        : index == 2
                            ? 1
                            : 1),
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          ),
        ),
```

**Sample output : **
[image]