# Prevent pictures from moving with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I have the same issue as this post.

[http://i.imgur.com/FUapm2K.gif?1](https://i.imgur.com/FUapm2K.gif?1)

[StaggeredGridLayoutManager and moving items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636999/staggeredgridlayoutmanager-and-moving-items)

However i can't understand the answer, here is the method i am calling inside the `OnBindViewHolder()` method of my adapter.

```
private void setRealSize(Post post, int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "setRealSize: width " + post.getWidthPost());
        Log.d(TAG, "setRealSize: height : " + post.getHeightPost());

        int percentWidth = (maxWidth / 3);
        double scaleFactor = (double) percentWidth / (double) post.getWidthPost();

        Log.d(TAG, "setRealSize: factor " + scaleFactor);
        Log.d(TAG, "setRealSize: height " + scaleFactor * post.getHeightPost());

        picturePreview.getLayoutParams().width = percentWidth;
        picturePreview.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (scaleFactor * post.getHeightPost());

}
```

My pictures are perfectly resized and keep their original aspect ratio. But i got the moving bug when i scroll up again...

And even if i would "store" these values for each picture, where and how should i use these values again if not with `getLayoutParams().height` ?

in my `Fragment` which contains the recycler view i only have for the StaggeredGridLayoutManager the following line of code :

`gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);`

Even if i remove the `DefaultAnimator` we can still see the change even if it's done much faster, it's quite ugly.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, but i am not giving up. I will post the answer here if i find it